# android re-open app set default activity

Tags: android, exit, lifecycle

If Home button is pressed, it will "quit" application. When quitted and re-opened it shows that activity/view where it was when quitted. How to make app to show default Launcher activity when re-opened ?

And other problem. I have 3 tabs(tabactivity), 2 of them content is listview and 3rd is "not-listview". In listview activities pushing return button will exit application. But in 3rd tabview it just do nothing. Why ? I havent programmed anything to do with return buttons. Its default behavior. I want 3rd one act like rest of two.

Comment: How your answer is answering my question, please ?

Comment: It's not which is why it's a comment and not an answer.

Comment: "If Home button is pressed, it will "quit" application." -- no, it does not. It brings the home screen's activity to the foreground. "When quitted and re-opened it shows that activity/view where it was when quitted." -- that depends on a number of factors, such as whether or not the app's process is still running and how the user "re-opened" the app. " In listview activities pushing return button will exit application." -- there is no "return button" in Android.

Comment: i think every android phone has a return button...

Answer (score 1):

You can implement this from your AndroidManifest.xml file, just adding

android:noHistory="true" attribute in those  you want i.e

Except launcher activity for other activities write above in manifest file

So when activity is launched after Home button pressed only the launcher activity will

be launched as other activities will be removed from stack.

Hope this is what you are looking for